# How to calculate dB based on frequency and volume in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am new to flutter, I am playing a audio in audio player for different volume and different frequencies. I want to find the decibels Hearing Level(dbHL) for it in flutter. How to find it.

I am expecting to calculate the Decibel Hearing Level for a particular volume and frequency.in flutter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Hello @Maria Merlin As per my knowledge and understanding, In order to determine the decibel hearing level (dBHL) in a Flutter application, you must first use audio processing libraries to measure the sound's decibel value. After that, make frequency-specific adjustments using standard audiograms, which plot the lowest sound levels at various frequencies that a person with normal hearing can distinguish. Through these modifications, the decibel value is adjusted to represent perceived loudness in dBHL. Present the user with the modified dBHL value at the end.

Please take a look at the following audio processing library; it might be beneficial for your needs.

- [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound)
- [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)
- [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)
- [audio_service (for background audio processing)](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service)